# Prove the uniform convergence of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Suppose $f \in C^1$ with a period of $2\pi$. Its Fourier series:
$$
f \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{f}(n) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n t}
$$
I want to prove that:
$$
\left\|f-S_{N}(f)\right\|_{\infty} \leqslant \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\left\|f^{\prime}\right\|_{2}, \quad \forall N \geqslant 1
$$
where $S_{n}(f)(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n} \widehat{f}(k) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k t}$, which means the uniform convergence of Fourier series.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$f(t)-S_N(f;t)\sim\sum_{|n|>N}\hat f(n)e^{int},$$while $$\sum_{|n|>N}|\hat f(n)|\le\left(\sum_{|n|>N}n^{-2}\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{|n|>N}n^2|\hat f(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac2N}||f'||_2.$$

Comment: Dear @David, what happened? Why did you keep deleting your posts?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I've got an official message to the effect that my answers contribute nothing but noise to the site. I don't want to do that, trying to clean up the damage i've done

Comment: Dear @David, I just want you to know that I love your answers. They are clear and educational.

Comment: Glad you've enjoyed them. As far as I ca tell from everything official I've heard in the almost two years I've been here, the fact that my answers are clear and educational has no relevance whatever.

Comment: They're probably the worst students you've had, who are just out to blame the Professor by telling him how awful his is. You know the type of student who assesses the Professor very quickly and does not give any benefit of doubt. I would just ignore students like that. They don't take into account the feelings of others. They lack humanity and empathy; they're just cold. You don't need the approval or respect of people like that. They'll always be condescending, rude and mean. They enjoy bringing down Professors by telling them them how awful they are. Students should coddle Professors.